# Set CXXFLAGS in Rcpp Makevars

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

I would like to set the C++ compiler flag to `-O0` in the Makevars of an Rcpp project.

If I take a look at `/etc/R/Makeconf`, I see that the compilation command seems to be

```
$(CXX) $(ALL_CPPFLAGS) $(ALL_CXXFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
```

Since

```
ALL_CXXFLAGS = $(R_XTRA_CXXFLAGS) $(PKG_CXXFLAGS) $(CXXPICFLAGS) $(SHLIB_CXXFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS)
```

I can edit in the Makevars the variable `$(PKG_CXXFLAGS)` to add headers for specific libraries, but I am not satisfied with `CXXFLAGS = -O3 -pipe  -g $(LTO)`. I would also like to be able to do that directly in the Makevars, so as to tune each project according to my needs.

When I edit `CXXFLAGS` in the Makevar, nothing happens. Is is possible to adjust that variable ? Is another approach possible ? I know that I can edit `~/.R/Makevars`, and switch as requested. I wondered if there was a more robust approach.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You generally want the `PKG_*` variants in your local file, e.g. `~/.R/Makevars`.

Here is a (shortened, edited) portion of mine:

```
## for C code
CFLAGS=               -O3 -g0 -Wall -pipe -pedantic -std=gnu99 

## for C++ code
#CXXFLAGS=             -g -O3 -Wall -pipe -Wno-unused -pedantic -std=c++11
CXXFLAGS=             -g -O3 -Wall -pipe -Wno-unused -pedantic 

## for Fortran code
#FFLAGS=-g -O3 -Wall -pipe
FFLAGS=-O3 -g0 -Wall -pipe
## for Fortran 95 code
#FCFLAGS=-g -O3 -Wall -pipe
FCFLAGS=-O3 -g0 -Wall -pipe

VER=-4.8
CC=ccache gcc$(VER)
CXX=ccache g++$(VER)
SHLIB_CXXLD=g++$(VER)
FC=ccache gfortran
F77=ccache gfortran
MAKE=make -j8
```

The other (system-global) approach is to create and edit `/etc/R/Makeconf.site` (or, when `/etc/R/` does not exist, `$RHOME/etc/R/Makeconf.site`.

Comment: Thanks. Editing the ~/.R/Makevars brings the added benefit that all the packages will have the debugging configuration, which might comes handy when including RcppEigen and such.

Comment: Eigen being mostly headers might not stand as the best example for that.

Comment: I don't know how you're supposed to find out about these flags but if your've set `CXX_STD = CXX11` then you will also need to use `CXX11FLAGS` which are used instead of `CXXFLAGS`. I assume the convention also applies for `CXX14` or `CXX17`.

Comment: That is correct and a more recent change (after I wrote the answer).