# How to I tell RStudio not to ignore the indication to use clang in Makevars?

Tags: c++, r, clang

I have this in `Makefile`

```
PKG_CC = clang-15
PKG_CXX = clang++-15
PKG_CXXFLAGS = -g -O0 -fopenmp
PKG_LIBS = $(SHLIB_OPENMP_CXXFLAGS)
CXX_STD = CXX11
PKG_CPPFLAGS = -UDEBUG -g
```

When I run `devtools::install()`, I see `g++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/usr/share/R/include"...` instead of `clang...`, which I expect because the next test worked:

```
> pkgbuild::check_build_tools(debug = TRUE)
Trying to compile a simple C file
Running /usr/lib/R/bin/R CMD SHLIB foo.c
using C compiler: ‘Ubuntu clang version 15.0.7’
clang-15 -I"/usr/share/R/include" -DNDEBUG       -fpic  -g -O2 -ffile-prefix-map=/build/r-base-JhpCKt/r-base-4.3.0=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2  -c foo.c -o foo.o
clang-15 -shared -L/usr/lib/R/lib -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -flto=auto -ffat-lto-objects -flto=auto -Wl,-z,relro -o foo.so foo.o -L/usr/lib/R/lib -lR
 
Your system is ready to build packages!
```

So far I deleted `.Rproj.user` and tried

```
devtools::clean_dll()
devtools::document()
devtools::install()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can ignore all `devtools` invocations here as well as all references to RStudio: these are just added layers. *Everything* eventually calls `R CMD INSTALL` so you can this directly.

In short, you file may have the wrong variables.  Here is a minimal one (as an actual subset of mine which I use to switch between `gcc` and `clang`)

```
CLANGVER=-15
CLANGLIB=-stdlib=libc++
CXX=$(CCACHE) clang++$(CLANGVER) $(CLANGLIB)
CXX11=$(CCACHE) clang++$(CLANGVER) $(CLANGLIB)
CXX14=$(CCACHE) clang++$(CLANGVER) $(CLANGLIB)
CXX17=$(CCACHE) clang++$(CLANGVER) $(CLANGLIB)
CXX20=$(CCACHE) clang++$(CLANGVER) $(CLANGLIB)
CC=$(CCACHE) clang$(CLANGVER)
SHLIB_CXXLD=clang++$(CLANGVER) $(CLANGLIB)
CXXFLAGS=-Wall -O3 -pedantic
CXX11FLAGS=-Wall -O3 -pedantic
CXX14FLAGS=-Wall -O3 -pedantic
CXX17FLAGS=-Wall -O3 -pedantic
CXX20FLAGS=-Wall -O3 -pedantic
```

I use `CLANGVER` as Ubuntu usually gives me a choice, and I use `VER` for `gcc`.  `CCACHE` is usually set (to `ccache`) but you can use it without it too as shown in the full log from a package here:

```
edd@rob:~/git/rcppexamples(master)$ ./cleanup; install.r   # install.r wraps R CMD INSTALL
* installing *source* package found in current working directory ...
* installing *source* package ‘RcppExamples’ ...
** using staged installation
** libs
using C++ compiler: ‘Ubuntu clang version 15.0.7’
clang++-15 -stdlib=libc++ -I"/usr/share/R/include" -DNDEBUG  -I'/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/Rcpp/include'     -fpic  -Wall -O3 -pedantic -c DataFrameExample.cpp -o DataFrameExample.o
clang++-15 -stdlib=libc++ -I"/usr/share/R/include" -DNDEBUG  -I'/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/Rcpp/include'     -fpic  -Wall -O3 -pedantic -c DateExample.cpp -o DateExample.o
clang++-15 -stdlib=libc++ -I"/usr/share/R/include" -DNDEBUG  -I'/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/Rcpp/include'     -fpic  -Wall -O3 -pedantic -c FactorExample.cpp -o FactorExample.o
clang++-15 -stdlib=libc++ -I"/usr/share/R/include" -DNDEBUG  -I'/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/Rcpp/include'     -fpic  -Wall -O3 -pedantic -c ListExample.cpp -o ListExample.o
clang++-15 -stdlib=libc++ -I"/usr/share/R/include" -DNDEBUG  -I'/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/Rcpp/include'     -fpic  -Wall -O3 -pedantic -c MatrixExample.cpp -o MatrixExample.o
clang++-15 -stdlib=libc++ -I"/usr/share/R/include" -DNDEBUG  -I'/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/Rcpp/include'     -fpic  -Wall -O3 -pedantic -c NumericVectorExample.cpp -o NumericVectorExample.o
clang++-15 -stdlib=libc++ -I"/usr/share/R/include" -DNDEBUG  -I'/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/Rcpp/include'     -fpic  -Wall -O3 -pedantic -c RNGs.cpp -o RNGs.o
clang++-15 -stdlib=libc++ -I"/usr/share/R/include" -DNDEBUG  -I'/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/Rcpp/include'     -fpic  -Wall -O3 -pedantic -c RcppExports.cpp -o RcppExports.o
clang++-15 -stdlib=libc++ -I"/usr/share/R/include" -DNDEBUG  -I'/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/Rcpp/include'     -fpic  -Wall -O3 -pedantic -c StringVectorExample.cpp -o StringVectorExample.o
clang++-15 -stdlib=libc++ -shared -L/usr/lib/R/lib -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -flto=auto -ffat-lto-objects -flto=auto -Wl,-z,relro -o RcppExamples.so DataFrameExample.o DateExample.o FactorExample.o ListExample.o MatrixExample.o NumericVectorExample.o RNGs.o RcppExports.o StringVectorExample.o -L/usr/lib/R/lib -lR
installing to /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/00LOCK-rcppexamples/00new/RcppExamples/libs
** R
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** testing if installed package can be loaded from temporary location
** testing if installed package can be loaded from final location
** testing if installed package keeps a record of temporary installation path
* DONE (RcppExamples)
edd@rob:~/git/rcppexamples(master)$
```

So in short you used the wrong variables. They differ between what we have to use in packages and their `src/Makevars` and what goes into `~/.R/Makevars`.  No prefix `PKG_` here, the 'global' one overrides what R has in its own `$RHOME/etc/Makeconf`.

Comment: Amazing answer. Thanks for the clarity. I must recognize this is a great improvement in both form and content from other answers I got here.

Comment: Thanks. It's maybe not the easiest term to search for but I am pretty sure I answered about `Makevars` before here.  Quick search:  [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22555526/set-cxxflags-in-rcpp-makevars/22557294?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C63.8983#22557294), [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68959897/rs-makevars-pkg-cxxflags-vs-pkg-cxx11flags/68959927?r=SearchResults&s=2%7C56.9873#68959927), [three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23414448/r-makevars-file-to-overwrite-r-cmds-default-g-options/23414789?r=SearchResults&s=3%7C56.0813#23414789).

Comment: I also wish the (nicely rendered via `quarto` [here](https://rstudio.github.io/r-manuals/)) had better search.

Comment: Previous comments misses 'R Manuals' which is what I was referring to.  My bad.